# How to Update Total Row in Grid from store in extjs4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have calculated Total Row using SummaryType:sum in Grid View Row. If the user selects combo, I need to display the Total Row value from store. My grid Values are coming from a different store. Can anybody tell me how to do this?

```
Ext.define('TestGrid.view.GlobalTeamTable1', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.globalteamtable1',

    id:'gridid',
     features: [{
        ftype: 'summary'
     }],
    store: Ext.create('TestGrid.store.TestResultStore'),
    columns: [{
        dataIndex: 'month',
        text: 'Month',
        summaryRenderer: function(){
            return '<b>Totals:</b>';
        }
    }, {
        dataIndex: 'target1',
        text: 'Target1',
        summaryType: 'sum'
    }, {
        dataIndex: 'target2',
        text: 'Target2',
        summaryType: 'sum'
    }, {
        dataIndex: 'targetDiff',
        text: 'Target(2-1)',
        summaryType: 'sum'

    }, {
        dataIndex: 'targetPercent',
        text: 'Target%',
        summaryType: function(records){
            var totals = records.reduce(function(sums, record){
                return [sums[0] + record.data.target2, 
                        sums[1] + record.data.targetDiff];
            }, [0,0]);

            return (totals[0] * totals[1]) / 100;
        }
    }]

});
```

Thanks

Comment: This is a bit vague, can you post some code, and explain better the calculation you need?

Comment: @Amit Aviv I have calculate total row summaryType: 'sum' in Grid View.Need to change or update store value in at the time of drop down selection

Comment: I don't understand.. The summary is not part of the store, the calculation is driven by the values in the store, and whenever you change the contents of the store (and the grid re-rendered) the summary will change.

Answer (score 0):

you could try update store with store.reload...

When I neew update data grid's I try reload the store.